# SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UserDetail_Id', table 'dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm getting a error When I'm trying to add data to my table. Please let me know whats wrong with my code. i have placed all my code. i hope that will help to you to understand my question.

Here is my action method 'RegisterButton'. in this action method i'm adding data to database.

```
public ActionResult RegisterButton(Models.Users User)
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
            {
                return View("Register", User);
            }

            else
            {
                db.Users.Add(User);
                db.SaveChanges();
                //Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format("~/App_Data/{0}",User.UserName+User.Id.ToString()));
                return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Profile", new { User.Id });
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my User Class & its properties:

```
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نام کاربريتان را وارد نماييد")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نام کاربريتان کمتر از 30 حرف برسانيد")]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نام کاربريتان بيشتر از 8 حرف برسانيد")]
    [Display(Name = " نام کاربری")]
    [Remote("CheckUserName","RegisterAndLogin","این نام کاربری قبا ثبت شده است")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا پسوردتان را وارد نماييد")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي پسورد کمتر از 30 حرف برسانيد")]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي پسورد بيشتر از 8 حرف برسانيد")]
    [Display(Name = " رمز عبور")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = " تکرار رمز عبور")]
    public string AgainPassword { get; set; }
    public Byte HashedPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا ايميلتان را وارد نماييد")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي ايميليتان کمتر از 50 حرف برسانيد")]
    [MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي ايميليتان بيشتر از 20 حرف برسانيد")]
    [Display(Name = " پست الکترونیک")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual UserDetails UserDetail { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("UserOwner")]
    public virtual ICollection<Images> OwnerImages { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("UserCreated")]
    public virtual ICollection<Images> CreatedImages { get; set; }

}
```

And This Is My UserDeatils Class:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="نام")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نامتان را وارد نماييد")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نامتان کمتر از 30 حرف برسانيد")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نامتان بيشتر از 3 حرف برسانيد")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا فاميليتان را وارد نماييد")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نامتان کمتر از 30 حرف برسانيد")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نامتان بيشتر از 3 حرف برسانيد")]
    [Display(Name = " نام خانوادگی")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا اسم پدر را وارد نماييد")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نام پدرتان را کمتر از 30 حرف برسانيد")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نام پدرتان را بيشتر از 3 حرف برسانيد")]
    [Display(Name = " نام پدر")]
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا اسم مادر را وارد نماييد")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نام مادرتان را کمتر از 30 حرف برسانيد")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "لطفا مقدار کاراکتر هاي نام پدرتان را بيشتر از 3 حرف برسانيد")]
    [Display(Name = " نام مادر")]
    public string MotherName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا سال تولدتان را وارد نماييد")]
    [Display(Name = " زمان تولد")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you don't show your table schema, if you don't show how the `User` is created, if you don't show the generated sql, how should we be able to help you? You'd better written some useful details.

Answer (score 0):

The `UserDetail_Id` is required in the `Users` table, so you should set it somewhere (in your case in the controller/`RegisterButton` function).

Possibly you should get a custom viewmodel from your view and map the data received to the `User` object.

Comment: I Have Get It With Post Like This:
public ActionResult RegisterButton(Users User)
{
}